# What are the expected winnings of this roulette strategy?

Tags: probability, expected-value

The following is an excerpt from exercise 2.28 in Mitzenmacher and Upfal's *Probability and Computing: Randomized Algorithms and Probabilistic Analysis*.

> Consider a simplified version of roulette in which you wager x dollars
> on either red or black. The wheel is spun, and you receive your
> original wager plus another $x$ dollars if the ball lands on your
> color; if the ball doesn't land on your color, you lose your wager.
> Each color occurs independently with probability 1/2. (This is a
> simplification because real roulette wheels have one or two spaces
> that are neither red nor black, so the probability of guessing the
> correct color is actually less than 1/2.)
>
> The following gambling strategy is a popular one. On the first spin,
> bet 1 dollar. If you lose, bet 2 dollars on the next spin. In general,
> if you have lost on the first $k-1$ spins, bet $2^{k-1}$ dollars on
> the $k$th spin.

The above problem provides context for exercise 2.30, which is stated as follows.

> In the roulette problem  of Exercise 2.28, we found that with
> probability  1 you  eventually  win  a dollar.  Let  $X_j$  be the
> amount you win on the $j$th bet. (This might be 0 if you have already
> won a previous bet.) Determine  $E[X_j]$  and show that, by applying the
> linearity  of expectations,  you find your expected winnings are 0.
> Does the linearity  of expectations hold in this case? (Compare with Exercise 2.29.)

I can't seem to get that my expected winnings are zero after applying linearity of expectation. My reasoning is as follows. Let's say that $X_j$ is $2^{j-1}$ if the $j$th bet is your first win, and $0$ otherwise. Then,

$$E[X_j] = 2^{j-1}\Pr(X_j = 2^{j-1}) = 2^{j-1}(1 - 1/2)^{j-1}(1/2) = 1/2$$

Now let $X$ be our total expected winnings. I'm not sure that linearity of expectation is applicable given that we aren't summing over a finite collection of random variables. Nor is it the case that $\sum_{j=1}^\infty E[|X_j|]$ converges, which would allow us to conclude linearity of expectation holds (the proof of this statement was exercise 2.29). However, if we follow the instructions of the problem anyway, applying linearity of expectation would give

$$E[X] = \sum_{j=1}^\infty E[X_j] = \sum_{j=1}^\infty 1/2 $$

which not only isn't 0 as the problem suggests, but isn't even bounded. Why is my answer different?

Comment: This as "martingale" well known strategy wins about a half chip per trial (since you need in average about $2$ coups to arrive at a win) until you pass the allowed limit with the next bet that would be necessary and have to concede a losing trial that is of course expensive if you played many stages. In a fair game, you win exactly a half-chip per trial in average until you lose a trial.

Comment: The phrase "amount you win" is a bit unclear, but I think the question means that $$X_j=\begin{cases} -2^{j-1} & \text{if you lose bet $j$}\\ 2^{j-1} &\text{if you win bet $j$}\\ 0 & \text{if you never reach bet $j$}\end{cases}$$.

Comment: In the portion of exercise 2.28 that I omitted, you are asked to determine the maximum expected loss before winning. I am of the impression that this problem concerns itself only with winnings. In other words, $X_j$ is 0 if you never reach bet $j$ or you lose bet $j$, and $2^{j-1}$ otherwise. It would be trivial to show that expected winnings are 0 if the problem is defined the way @JamesMartin suggests, no?

Comment: @kotu I can see why you might think that, but it doesn't fit with the rest of the question.What the question is driving at is this. Define $X_j$ as I wrote (your profit, positive or negative or zero, at bet $j$). Notice that each term in the sum $X:=\sum_{j\geq 1} X_j$ has expectation $E[X_j]=0$ (indeed, this is "trivial" as you say). However, the sum $X$ does not have expectation $0$; in fact, $X$ takes value $1$ with probability $1$, so $E[X]=1$. So "linearity of expectation" fails in this case, as you suspected.